# Optimize data upload on GoogleBigQuery

Tags: optimization, bigdata, google-bigquery

I'm currently using the Google BigQuery platform for uploading many datas (~ > 6 Go) and work with them as datasource with Tableau Desktop Software.
Presently it takes me an average of one hour to upload 12 tables in CSV format (total of 6 Go), uncompressed, with a python script using the Google API.
The google docs specify that "If loading speed is important to your app and you have a lot of bandwidth to load your data, leave files uncompressed.".
How can I optimize this process ? Should be a solution to compressed my csv files to improve the upload speed ?
I also think about using Google Cloud Storage, but I expect my problem will be the same?
I need to reduce the time it's take me to upload my data files, but I don't find great solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Compressing your input data will reduce the time to upload the data, but will increase the time for the load job to execute once your data has been uploaded (compression restricts our ability to process your data in parallel). Since it sounds like you'd prefer to optimize for upload speed, I'd recommend compressing your data.

Note that if you're willing to split your data into several chunks and compress them each individually, you can get the best of both worlds--fast uploads and parallel load jobs.

Uploading to Google Cloud Storage should have the same trade-offs, except for one advantage: you can specify multiple source files in a single load job. This is handy if you pre-shard your data as suggested above, because then you can run a single load job that specifies several compressed input files as source files.